# Cordova IOS emulator for Meteorjs fails

Tags: android, ios, cordova, meteor

So I've added the meteor ios platform to my meteor application. Everytime I try to run the emulator I get this error.

```
=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/     
=> Errors executing Cordova commands:         

While running Cordova app for platform iOS with options --emulator:
Error: Command failed:                     
/Users/Cpena1/Documents/testingMeteor/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/cordova/run
--emulator
ENOENT, no such file or directory
'/Users/Cpena1/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/1FB66CCA-7E03-408A-B240-A2D4098B356D/system.log'
Error code 1 for command: ios-sim with args:
launch,/Users/Cpena1/Documents/testingMeteor/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/build/emulator/testingMeteor.app,--  devicetypeid,com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6,--stderr,/Users/Cpena1/Documents/testingMeteor/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log,--stdout,/Users/Cpena1/Documents/testingMeteor/.meteor/local/cordova-build/platforms/ios/cordova/console.log,--exit
at ChildProcess.exitCallback (/tools/utils/processes.js:137:23)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:12)

ExitWithCode:1
```

I've tried removing the Cordova file and even reinstalled Meteor. The simulator will open in Xcode but it will only appear with a black screen.

Answer (score 0):

I similarly got stuck on the splash screen. My workaround was to add 
     --production 
to the command line.